# ggplot2 and geom_density: How to remove baseline?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot` as described here

[Smoothed density estimates](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html)

and entered in the R console

```
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(x = rating))
m + geom_density()
```

This works but is there some way to remove the connection between the x-axis and the density plot (the vertical lines which connect the density plot to the x-axis)

Answer (score 68):

The most consistent way to do so is (thanks to @baptiste):

```
m + stat_density(geom="line")
```

My original proposal was to use `geom_line` with an appropriate `stat`:

```
m + geom_line(stat="density")
```

but it is no longer recommended since I'm receiving reports it's not universally working for every case in newer versions of ggplot.

Comment: or `stat_density` with an appropriate `geom`

Comment: Thanks for the note! Included that option to the answer.

Comment: `geom='line'` seems no longer to work with `ggplot2 2.1.0`

Comment: Doesn't seem to give the same output with groupings for me.

Comment: Can also confirm that `stat_density(geom='line')` doesn't work with groupings, while `geom_line(stat='density')` is fine

Comment: For groupings, the `geom_line(stat="density")`  produces the correct picture, because `stat_density(geom="line")` produce density without equal area under the curve for two density lines.

Comment: I am using ggplot2 version 3.1.1, as of February of 2020. Interestingly, for negative values (as adding a `scale_y_log10` creates), the option `geom_line(stat='density')` works, while the `stat_density(geom='line')` doesn't

Answer (score 8):

The suggested answers dont provide exactly the same results as `geom_density`. Why not draw a white line over the baseline?

```
+ geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="white", size=1)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The drawback is that the background of the plot may or may not be white, depending on axis settings etc.

Answer (score 7):

Another way would be to calculate the density separately and then draw it. Something like this:

```
a <- density(movies$rating)
b <- data.frame(a$x, a$y)
ggplot(b, aes(x=a.x, y=a.y)) + geom_line()
```

It's not exactly the same, but pretty close.