# How to remove colored line on the x axis with geom_density from ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please, does anyone knows how to remove this colored line on the x axis? The dataframe is `dfp`.

```
                 Value          Class
   1             94.00             A
   2             70.51             A
   3             70.02             A
   4             95.24             A
   5             70.53             A
   6             93.01             A
   7             70.86             A
   8             94.84             A
   9             70.77             A
```

I´m using this command line to plot:

```
ggplot(dfp, aes(na.omit(dfp$Value),  color = na.omit(dfp$Class), alpha=0.3) ) + geom_density(size=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600754/ggplot2-and-geom-density-how-to-remove-baseline?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(...) + stat_density(geom = "line")
```

The default `geom` is `area`, but you can change it to `line`. The benefit of the default is being able to shade the area (with a `fill =` aesthetic), rather than outline it.

Comment: And add `position = "identity"`, because the default is `"stack"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `geom_freqpoly()` instead of `geom_density()`.

Best,

Colin

Comment: Thanks! But I need the frequency density. It seems that `geom_freqpoly()` works only with discrete values, right?