# How to remove curves after last datapoint in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I want to erase a part of a density curve in ggplot for places where there are no data points.
If you add a density curve, the program automatically adds density estimation curve.
I have to erase the part after the last data point. There are multiple curves, so setting a range to x-axis was not an option.
For example, in the sample iris data, I want to remove the parts marked in orange.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
summary(iris)

setosa <- iris %>%filter(Species== 'setosa')
versicolor <- iris %>%filter(Species== 'versicolor')
virginica <- iris %>%filter(Species== 'virginica')

summary(setosa)
summary(versicolor)
summary(virginica)

p <- ggplot(setosa, aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_density()
p
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 and geom\_density: how to remove baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600754/ggplot2-and-geom-density-how-to-remove-baseline)

Comment: @s_t similar, but not dupe, when trying suggested answers lines do not "touch" the x-axis at zero. Try: `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + stat_density(geom = "line")`

Comment: @zx8754 retracted the close vote, thanks.

Comment: Try adding `trim = TRUE` inside `geom_density()`? Or is your use case so specific that you want to keep one end while trimming the other?

Answer (score 0):

The follow is far from ideal but it is the solution I came up with so here we go. It basically uses the modifier system introduced in ggplot2 v3.3.0 to make datapoints beyond your limit `NA`s, which get dropped automatically.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
})
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2

data(iris)

setosa <- iris %>%filter(Species== 'setosa')
versicolor <- iris %>%filter(Species== 'versicolor')
virginica <- iris %>%filter(Species== 'virginica')

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_density(data = setosa,
               aes(x = stage(Sepal.Length, after_stat = ifelse(x > 5.8, NA, x)))) +
  geom_density(data = versicolor,
               aes(x = stage(Sepal.Length, after_stat = ifelse(x > 7, NA, x)))) +
  geom_density(data = virginica,
               aes(x = stage(Sepal.Length, after_stat = ifelse(x > 7.9, NA, x))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Another strategy would be to precompute your densities with `stats::density()` and then cut them manually.